# Getting contents of new tab opened using Mechanize Ruby

Tags: ruby, mechanize

I am using ruby mechanize to submit form. When I submit form results are opened in new tab.I don't how to get contents of new tab opened. Please anyone help me to get content of new tab opened using mechanize. I also did google but I didn't get much help.
Please help me...
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I don't see what's special about submitting a form and being taken to a new page, whether it's in the same tab or not. A concept of a tab is typically defined by web browser (think Firefox or Chrome). If you're using Mechanize, you're not really using a web browser.

The [example](http://mechanize.rubyforge.org/GUIDE_rdoc.html) from Mechanize's guide explains it:

```
agent = Mechanize.new
first_page = agent.get('http://google.com/')
google_form = page.form('f')
google_form.q = 'some search string'
```

Submitting a form returns a bunch of HTML, whether that is a new "page" or a new "tab"

```
second_page_or_tab = agent.submit(google_form)
```

To view the page you can pretty print:

```
pp second_page_or_tab
```